# accessing a form.vars.value in a if statement (TWIG)

Tags: symfony, if-statement, twig

I try to select a forms-fields value in twig so that I can display a red/green status if the element is active oder deactivated.

But it wont work, I always get a

```
Impossible to access an attribute ("enabled") on a NULL variable ("")
```

This is my Code am I'm unsure if there are some missing braces or sth like that?

```
{% if form.vars.value.enabled is null %}
        <h2 class="device-off">
    {% else %}
        <h2 class="device-on">
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dump to see form.vars variable

```
{{ dump(form.vars) }}
```

Comment: The solution above works ... if you use the right parameters for the db request ;( 

I found it while  I was using the dump

{{ dump(form.vars.value.enabled)}}